# Showing another page in Microsoft Visual Studio (Universal Windows App) by clicking on a button

Tags: windows

I have wanted to show a page in visual studio 2019 *(Universal Windows project)* by clicking on a button in MainPage.

I know Visual Basic coding a little so I thought it will be okay to use `page2.show()`. But when I used it, an error occurred and didn't work.

Please reply me and tell me what to do!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a XAML page called "page2.xaml", the correct syntax for page navigation is:

```
Frame.Navigate(GetType(page2));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me. I used this code but it didn't work!

Comment: What language is your project in ? Is it C# or VB.NET?

Comment: It's Visual Basic ( VB.NET )

Comment: See the edit then. `Typeof` is a C# thing, the VB equivalent is GetType

Comment: Now, the code is correct, but it's written here that Page2 doesn't exist! I'm completely sure that I created a file named Page2.xaml

Comment: Is page2.xaml listed under the Solution Explorer? The file has to be in the project for this to work, so that the code-behind class `page2` is compiled along with MainPage.